# What is the best practice add video background view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, video

I want to add background view with video (or gif) like in app "Uber" 
I'd like to use video background view for a long time in my app.

And I want to know the answers to these questions:

- What of them will consume less battery energy
- Can I use it on iPhone or iPad
- Performance of this method

Screenshot of the registration form

[image]

Comment: "Best practice" question do not encourage the asker to show effort. There-for they are not suitable for Stack Overflow. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing

Comment: I agree with you, but If I want to use that or another method of background View for a long time, I want to know, what of them will consume less battery energy and can I use it on iPhone or iPad.

Comment: So your question just became a very nice example, why best practice questions are bad: How should someone be able the anticipate this just by asking for best practice?

Comment: And now you got 5 answers that do not answer your edited question anymore.

Comment: @vikingosegundo Another time I will be smarter ...

Comment: delete this question, post it rephrased.

Comment: Loved this question with the UBER rip off style jajajaja! :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all,

you have two main choices: use a **imageView with a GIF** or **use a video for background with AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayerController**. You can find a lot of example for both ways, here's a few:

- [use a GIF for cool background](https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-make-an-awesome-video-background-view-objective-c-swift-318e1d71d0a2)
- [video cover iOS](https://github.com/bichenkk/VideoCover-iOS-Demo)

In reply to your questions:

> What of them will consume less battery energy

Generally use a video: as noted by the user *vikingosegundo* video are usually optimized and their codecs deal with GPUs; displaying a GIF should be a only "CPU-job" because it's just show a loop of frames. So the energy comparison is between a simple loop of frames (GIF) and a more complex frames loop that can be accelerated in many ways (video). In my experience however a small GIF give a good performance anyway.

> Can I use it on iPhone or iPad

In both but you have to be careful with aspect ratio and autolayout constraints

> Performance of this method

Excellent in both cases but you have to be careful about the size of your GIF or video: bigger is your file (GIF or video), worse should be the performance. For video more precisely, higher is the quality worse should be the performance while the duration of the video shouldn't be impact.

Comment: Why would gif consume less energy?

Comment: Thanks for your answer @MassimoPolimeni, I think I will find golden mean between performance and quality.

Comment: @ vikingosegundo I added more info :) now my answer is more accurate. @TikhonovAlexander ;) have fun and do some test for find the best choice

Comment: i have no real data to depend on. but I see my computer's cpu ramp high for displaying short GIFs, but usually not for 2 hour long big resolution MPGs. Videos are highly optimize and their codecs deal with GPUs. I doubt that for GIFs.

Comment: This is a good point. I see that with small GIF the consumption on devices are really small but I never investigated so much about the comparison with video. So thank's for commented on this, you made me searching more info about it and for sure I'll update my answer!

Answer (score 4):

One of the popular and open source library for Background video play library sample source code download from below link

1. [VideoCover-iOS-Demo](https://github.com/bichenkk/VideoCover-iOS-Demo)
2. [AMLoginViewController Uses GPUImage For Filter videos.](https://github.com/mtonio91/AMLoginViewController)

May this help lot.

Comment: It's complete full fill your requirement @TikhonovAlexander

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lot of open-source components for this purpose.

For example, this one supports GIF, movie playback

https://github.com/kaiinui/KIChameleonView

Or this for GIF playback

https://github.com/liyong03/YLGIFImage

Answer (score 0):

You can use the video directly & Play it repeat mode,

OR

You can use images along with default `animationImages` property of `UIImageView` Class.

Like Below,

```
 YourImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:  
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_1.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_2.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_3.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_4.png"],
                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample_5.png"],
                                   nil];

 // How many seconds it should take to go through all images one time.
 YourImageView.animationDuration = 5.0;

 // How many times to repeat the animation (0 for indefinitely).
 YourImageView.animationRepeatCount = 4;

 [YourImageView startAnimating];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the set of images in `.png` or `.jpeg` format and assign images to the `UIImageView`:

```
UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 548)];

//Add images which will be used for the animation using an array. Here I have created an array on the fly
NSMutableArray *drawingImgs = [NSMutableArray array];
[drawingImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"]];
[drawingImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"]];
[drawingImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"]];
[drawingImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"]];
[drawingImgs addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"]];

backgroundImageView.animationImages = drawingImgs;
//Set the duration of the entire animation
backgroundImageView.animationDuration = 0.5;

//Set the repeat count. If you don't set that value, by default will be a loop (infinite)
backgroundImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1;

//Start the animationrepeatcount
[backgroundImageView startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

I used xCode 7 and iOS 9.
I used gif image and it work correctly.

```
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Name of your image" ofType:@"gif"];
    NSData *gif = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    UIWebView *webViewBG = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [webViewBG loadData:gif MIMEType:@"image/gif" textEncodingName:nil baseURL:nil];
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:webViewBG];
```